# Retrieve single record from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

It feels this should be simple but its not working. I am doing an app in Android with Firebase. My database is of different questions, this is the test json I imported to Firebase

```
{
  "multiple_choice" : {
        "-K3ib4H77rj0LYewF7dP" : {
          "question" : "question1?",
          "options" : {
            "0" : "one",
            "1" : "two",
            "2" : "three"
          }
        },
        "-K6ib4H77rj0LYewF7dP" : {
          "question" : "question2?",
          "options" : {
            "0" : "one",
            "1" : "two",
            "2" : "three"
          }
        },
        "-K9ib4H77rj0LYewF7dP" : {
          "question" : "question3?",
          "options" : {
            "0" : "one",
            "1" : "two",
            "2" : "three"
          }
        }
    }
}
```

All I want to do is from opening a new intent (where a question id is passed), return that child from Firebase and update the layout fields accordingly eg. for question id "-K9ib4H77rj0LYewF7dP" - return question and options for that one. The example I tried uses onDataChanged and DataSnapshot which is probably not what I'm looking for.

Comment: onDataChanged is exactly what you're looking for. I recommend you read the Firebase docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write and watch the Firecasts for Android Developers: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLmxfvI4Ds2Atko79iVvxlaq

Answer (score 0):

I got it by using addListenerForSingleValueEvent(). Took some experimenting with node paths but that was the right place to start.